# How to optimize this slow query with multiple ANDs and ORs

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-workbench

Here is my query,

```
SELECT  transaktion.betrag_eur
FROM transaktion_buchung AS transaktion
WHERE transaktion.fk_kunde=303276 
  AND transaktion.konto='Cashback' 
  AND transaktion.storniert_am IS NULL 
  AND transaktion.freigegeben_am IS NULL  
  AND (transaktion.buchungstyp!='Zahlung' OR transaktion.buchungstyp IS NULL)
```

I get incorrect key file error for this query due to disk space limits. How can I optimize this query?

and EXPLAIN for this query displays this,

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    653631  Using where
2   DERIVED transaktion ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    428809  
2   DERIVED buchung ref fk_buchung_transaktion  fk_buchung_transaktion  5   card4students.transaktion.id    1   Using where; Not exists
2   DERIVED filiale eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   card4students.transaktion.fk_filiale    1   
3   UNION   buchung ref konto   konto   1       337602  Using where
3   UNION   transaktion eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   card4students.buchung.fk_transaktion    1   
3   UNION   filiale eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   card4students.transaktion.fk_filiale    1   
3   UNION   auszahlung  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   card4students.buchung.fk_auszahlung 1   
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union2,3>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

In this case, transaktion_buchung is a view.

Schema for transaktion_buchung:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `db_card4students`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `transaktion_buchung` AS
(
SELECT 
        `transaktion`.`fk_kunde` AS `fk_kunde`,
        `transaktion`.`id` AS `fk_transaktion`,
        `buchung`.`id` AS `fk_buchung`,
        NULL AS `auszahlung_gewuenscht`,
        `transaktion`.`betrag_eur` AS `betrag_eur`,
        `transaktion`.`nettoumsatz` AS `nettoumsatz`,
        `transaktion`.`mwst` AS `mwst`,
        NULL AS `fk_abrechnung`,
        `filiale`.`name` AS `filiale_name`,
        `transaktion`.`storniert_am` AS `storniert_am`,
        `transaktion`.`freigegeben_am` AS `freigegeben_am`,
        `buchung`.`buchungstyp` AS `buchungstyp`,
        `transaktion`.`konto` AS `konto`,
        0 AS `auszahlung_vorgenommen`,
        `transaktion`.`recordbirthdate` AS `recordbirthdate`
    FROM
        ((`transaktion`
        LEFT JOIN `buchung` ON ((`buchung`.`fk_transaktion` = `transaktion`.`id`)))
        LEFT JOIN `filiale` ON ((`filiale`.`id` = `transaktion`.`fk_filiale`)))
    WHERE
        ISNULL(`buchung`.`id`)
) UNION ALL (
SELECT 
        `buchung`.`fk_kunde` AS `fk_kunde`,
        `buchung`.`fk_transaktion` AS `fk_transaktion`,
        `buchung`.`id` AS `fk_buchung`,
        `buchung`.`auszahlung_gewuenscht` AS `auszahlung_gewuenscht`,
        `buchung`.`betrag_eur` AS `betrag_eur`,
        `transaktion`.`nettoumsatz` AS `nettoumsatz`,
        `transaktion`.`mwst` AS `mwst`,
        `auszahlung`.`fk_abrechnung` AS `fk_abrechnung`,
        `filiale`.`name` AS `filiale_name`,
        `transaktion`.`storniert_am` AS `storniert_am`,
        IF(ISNULL(`transaktion`.`id`),
            NOW(),
            `transaktion`.`freigegeben_am`) AS `freigegeben_am`,
        `buchung`.`buchungstyp` AS `buchungstyp`,
        `buchung`.`konto` AS `konto`,
        `buchung`.`auszahlung_vorgenommen` AS `auszahlung_vorgenommen`,
        IF((`transaktion`.`recordbirthdate` IS NOT NULL),
            `transaktion`.`recordbirthdate`,
            `buchung`.`recordbirthdate`) AS `recordbirthdate`
    FROM
        (((`buchung`
        LEFT JOIN `transaktion` ON ((`transaktion`.`id` = `buchung`.`fk_transaktion`)))
        LEFT JOIN `filiale` ON ((`filiale`.`id` = `transaktion`.`fk_filiale`)))
        LEFT JOIN `auszahlung` ON ((`auszahlung`.`id` = `buchung`.`fk_auszahlung`)))
    WHERE
        (`buchung`.`konto` = _UTF8'Cashback')
)
```

Comment: 1) Buy bigger box 2) Add index to `transaktion_buchung` table

Comment: post your `transaktion_buchung` schema

Comment: did anybody ask you for the `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: is it the EXPLAIN for the same query?

Comment: Is transaktion_buchung a table or a view? Looking at the EXPLAIN I suspect it is a view. If so can you post the view and the declares of the tables in the view please

Comment: Hi Kickstart, yes it is a view.

Comment: MySQL is very poor for using views. It just views them as a sub query an doesn't use indexes to narrow the results down. You are probably better off taking the SELECT used for the view and using it directly (with the where clauses in your above select).

Answer (score 0):

To optimize this query, you just need a composite index:

```
create index idx_transaktion_buchung on
    transaktion_buchung(fk_kunde, konto, stonriert, freigegeben_am, buchungstyp, betrag_eur);
```

This is a covering index for the query, so should be quite fast.

Comment: is it necessary to put `betrag_eur` into index?

Comment: `stonriert` should be `stonriert_am`?

Comment: transaktion_buchung is a view. I've added the relevant schema in the question details

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that MySQL is not using any indexes very usefully. It is probably returning a very large result set (using indexes for the joins), but then scanning through every returned row to check the values you look for in the WHERE clause.

As such it is probably worth trying to write the query without using a view. Something like this I think:-

```
SELECT  transaktion.fk_kunde AS fk_kunde, 
    transaktion.id AS fk_transaktion,  
    buchung.id AS fk_buchung, 
    NULL AS auszahlung_gewuenscht,  
    transaktion.betrag_eur AS betrag_eur, 
    transaktion.nettoumsatz AS nettoumsatz,  
    transaktion.mwst AS mwst, 
    NULL AS fk_abrechnung,  
    filiale.name AS filiale_name,  
    transaktion.storniert_am AS storniert_am, 
    transaktion.freigegeben_am AS freigegeben_am,  
    buchung.buchungstyp AS buchungstyp,  
    transaktion.konto AS konto, 
    0 AS auszahlung_vorgenommen, 
    transaktion.recordbirthdate AS recordbirthdate 
FROM transaktion 
LEFT JOIN buchung ON buchung.fk_transaktion = transaktion.id
LEFT JOIN filiale ON filiale.id = transaktion.fk_filiale
WHERE ISNULL(buchung.id) 
AND transaktion.fk_kunde=303276 
AND transaktion.konto='Cashback' 
AND transaktion.storniert_am IS NULL 
AND transaktion.freigegeben_am IS NULL  
AND (transaktion.buchungstyp!='Zahlung' 
OR transaktion.buchungstyp IS NULL)
UNION ALL 
SELECT  buchung.fk_kunde AS fk_kunde,  
    buchung.fk_transaktion AS fk_transaktion, 
    buchung.id AS fk_buchung,  
    buchung.auszahlung_gewuenscht AS auszahlung_gewuenscht, 
    buchung.betrag_eur AS betrag_eur,  
    transaktion.nettoumsatz AS nettoumsatz, 
    transaktion.mwst AS mwst,  
    auszahlung.fk_abrechnung AS fk_abrechnung,  
    filiale.name AS filiale_name,  
    transaktion.storniert_am AS storniert_am, 
    IF(ISNULL(transaktion.id), NOW(),  transaktion.freigegeben_am) AS freigegeben_am, 
    buchung.buchungstyp AS buchungstyp,  
    buchung.konto AS konto, 
    buchung.auszahlung_vorgenommen AS auszahlung_vorgenommen, 
    IF((transaktion.recordbirthdate IS NOT NULL),  
    transaktion.recordbirthdate, buchung.recordbirthdate) AS recordbirthdate 
FROM buchung 
LEFT JOIN transaktion ON transaktion.id = buchung.fk_transaktion 
LEFT JOIN filiale ON filiale.id = transaktion.fk_filiale
LEFT JOIN auszahlung ON auszahlung.id = buchung.fk_auszahlung
WHERE buchung.konto = _UTF8'Cashback'
AND buchung.fk_kunde=303276 
AND transaktion.storniert_am IS NULL 
AND transaktion.freigegeben_am IS NULL  
AND transaktion.id IS NOT NULL 
AND transaktion.freigegeben_am IS NULL
AND (buchung.buchungstyp!='Zahlung' 
OR buchung.buchungstyp IS NULL)
```

You will probably need a compound index on buchung covering fk_kunde and konto . And on transaktion a compound index covering fk_kunde and konto.